# Prevent windows 7 from logging off

Tags: windows, account

This question sounds like an easy task and something everyone should know.
But my situation is a bit difference. In my office we are logging to our windows 7 through a domain with our own password and username. Therefore we don't have any access to the user control panel.
The account will automatically log off after 10 minute of inactivity. If i open a MS powerpoint, and make it loop infinity, the account will never log off cause i guess windows sees the powerpoint loop as an activity. I don't want to have this powerpoint looping on my screen. So is it another way i can prevent my account to log off. Some sort of a program running at the background or anything else?

Comment: Probably `SetThreadExecutionState`.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry that I have to give this answer.
But the right way to go is to ask your Domain Administrator / IT Expert to adjust the Domain Policy / GPO.

I would not accept this as a user / employee aswell.

There is a GPO which instead puts on the Screensaver which also locks the Screen but doesnt Close your session.

Feel free to ask me if you need the exact GPO Settings for this workaround.

PS: There are also programs which auto-move your mouse cursor a little while you're afk.